# Read model properties and values using Custom Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute. Is it possible to read the model properties and it's value in there?

Comment: Have you explored values coming in to controllerContext and methodInfo parameters?

Comment: Have you tried if its possible...?

Comment: This will help http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=724